# Converting data from firebase to an object does not work because of timestamp

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I need to convert data from firebase to an object, but I get an error because of the Timestamp:

```
type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

In the model I added toDate() to the 'createdAt' but I still get the error.
How can I solve this in flutter?

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class AnimalWithLoc {
  final String username;
  final String userId;
  final double longitude;
  final double latitude;
  final List<String> imageUrls;
  final String description;
  final DateTime createdAt;
  final String address;

  AnimalWithLoc(
    this.username,
    this.userId,
    this.longitude,
    this.latitude,
    this.imageUrls,
    this.description,
    this.createdAt,
    this.address,
  );

  AnimalWithLoc.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : username = map['username'],
        userId = map['userId'],
        longitude = map['longitude'],
        latitude = map['latitude'],
        imageUrls = map['imageUrls'],
        description = map['description'],
        createdAt = (map["createdAt"] as Timestamp).toDate(),
        address = map['address'];
}
```

in body.dart the foreach works correctly

```
...
final animalDocs = animalSnapshot.data!.docs;
final List<AnimalWithLoc> loadedAnimals = [];

for (var i = 0; i < animalDocs.length; i++) {
   var currAnim = animalDocs[i].data();
   currAnim.forEach((key, value) {
      // print(value);
      loadedAnimals.add(AnimalWithLoc.fromMap(value));
   });
}
...
```

Comment: What happens if you simply use `map["createdAt"].toDate()`?

Comment: I get the same error: type 'Timestamp' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: Make sure that "createdAt" is of type `Timestamp` as I think it maybe a data error and your "createdAt" is not what you think. Try printing the result and view it before making the parsing.

Comment: I run value.runtimeType and I get ```Timestamp``` and the value is for example ```Timestamp(seconds=1640274007, nanoseconds=823733000)```

Comment: What about removing `forEach` loop and simply using: `loadedAnimals.add(AnimalWithLoc.fromMap(currAnim));`?

Comment: That does not work. I get this error: ```type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are losing the `toDate()` method when you pass the data as a `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Try this in `body.dart`:

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < animalDocs.length; i++) {
   var currAnim = animalDocs[i].data();
   final createdAt = DateTime.parse(currAnim["createdAt"].toDate().toString());
}
```